# Accessing a string variable from another View in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to get the SpotifyAccessToken from my LoginViewController to my GuestPartyViewController.

```
 class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var spotifyLoginBtn: UIButton!

var spotifyId = ""
var spotifyDisplayName = ""
var spotifyEmail = ""
var spotifyAvatarURL = ""
var spotifyAccessToken = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    spotifyLoginBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```

And I need to use that variable in the searchURL of my GuestPartyViewController.

```
     import UIKit
 import Alamofire
 import AVFoundation
 class GuestPartyViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var partyNameLabel: UILabel!
var partyName: String?
@IBOutlet weak var partyDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
var partyDescription: String?
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var spotifyAccessToken: String?

var searchURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Kanye%20West&type=track&access_token=\(spotifyAccessToken)" // The error here is: Cannot use instance member 'spotifyAccessToken' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available


 class DetailsViewController:UIViewController {

 var spotifyAccessToken: String?
 @IBAction func startPartyButton(_ sender: Any) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "startParty", sender: self)
 }
 @IBAction func joinPartyButton(_ sender: Any) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "joinPartySeg", sender: self)
 }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if(segue.identifier == "startParty") {
     let GuestPartyVC = segue.destination as! GuestPartyViewController 
 // Here is where I get the error
     GuestPartyVC.spotifyAccessToken = spotifyAccessToken
 }
 }
```

I was thinking about declaring it in the app delegate, but I'm not sure how to do that since it is first declared in the LoginViewController.

Comment: So the first screen in your application is the `LoginViewController`'s screen, and after login you go to the `GuestPartyViewController`'s screen?

Comment: After LoginViewController I go to another ViewController that then goes to the GuestPartyView controller. I have to do this to give the option to either join or create a new party.

Answer (score 1):

After performing login in `LoginViewController` and getting the token pass it to the next view controller whatever it is, and pass it again from that view controller to `GuestPartyViewController' so that you can use it.

To pass the token you can either pass it by injecting it through the initialiser of the next view controller or by overriding `prepare(for:sender:)` method like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Do check for the next view controller and set the value of the token here
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I get an error on the second segue that says "cannot cast value of type" It seems like there is an error when passing it to the third view controller.

Comment: I commented the DetailsViewController where I was getting the error as an answer to this question for you.

Comment: Make sure that `"startParty"` segue identifier is set only to the segue that navigates you from `DetailsViewController` to `GuestPartyViewController`. Also please don't add your comment as an answer, I suggest you remove it and add it to your question's body :)

Comment: Really appreciate all your help. Sorry I am very much a beginner with all of this. Now I am confused why when I try to add that variable to my searchURL it gives me an error. I have updated my GuestPartyViewController code above with the error that I get.

Comment: I did. If you scroll to the right it is on the same line as the searchURL.

Comment: `searchURL` is a property of `GuestPartyViewController` and same for `spotifyAccessToken`. In order for an instance of `GuestPartyViewController` to be initialised, all its properties need to be initialised. In your case, this property `searchURL` needs to `spotifyAccessToken` to be initialised and this is not possible. You can fix this by defining `searchURL` as a lazy property like this: `lazy searchURL = "..........". This way it will only be initialised when it is actually used.